# Crash When Creating MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to have a video play when my app launches for the first time but it crashes on:

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"]]];
```

I have a property for moviePlayer in the .h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

Here is the all of the code for it:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasPerformedFirstLaunch"])
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSLog(@"file exists so init player");

        self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"]]];
        [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, width - 20, height - 10)];
        self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
        [self.moviePlayer play];

        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"file not found");
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasPerformedFirstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Please post the crash log and debugger output.

Comment: Your file extensions are different when you are loading vs when you are searching (`@"mp4"` vs `@"m4v"`). And since you have set a property for the `MPMoviePlayerController` why aren't you using `self.moviePlayer` instead of `moviePlayer`?

Comment: It should be m4v. The code I originally posted had the wrong file type in it but I've updated the post.

Comment: As @rckoenes mentioned earlier, the crash log would help

Comment: @spassas, I figured out that it's crashing because it isn't finding the file in mainBundle. I copied the file into the project so I'm not sure why it isn't finding it.

Comment: in my experience, this would not cause the app to crash, it would just not play anything.

Comment: @spassas, it was in fact crashing because the file wasn't in the correct place. I added it correctly and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the MediaPlayer framework?

```
@import MediaPlayer
```

Comment: Yes, it is imported in the .h file. I've updated my post. It looks like the file isn't in my mainBundle. I'm just not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the file wasn't located in the mainBundle. i got it added to the mainBundle and it is working as expected.